What is noptr-declarator in C++ array declaration?
I was reeading about Array declaration in C++ (cppreference-Array declaration) and there is a rule with declarator before [size] when you declare a new array.

noptr-declarator - any valid declarator, but if it begins with *, &, or &&, it has to be surrounded by parentheses.

I understand you cannot make &, && arrays without parentheses, however can't I do something like this with * pointer?
// compiles fine without () ???
// array of (3 pointers to int)
int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
int *array_of_pointers[3] = { &x, &y, &z };

char abc[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
// pointer to (array of 3 chars)
char (*pointer_to_abc_array)[3] = &abc;

array_of_pointers begins with *, but it "didn't have to" surrounded with parentheses? What is going on here? Why cppreference says declarator starts with * should be surrounded with parentheses while it also works without them?

*array_of_pointers[3] is a pointer declarator. The inner part, array_of_pointers[3], is an array declarator that does not contain *.

int *a[3]; is not an array declarator. It is the declaration of an array, but that's not the same thing at all. Declarators and declarations are different syntactic categories.

@user12002570 thats not correct https://eel.is/c++draft/generalindex#:declarator

Oh, Thank you for all your answers! I will just "reference" the cppreference from now on with caution haha

I dont understand whats the point of picking on cppref vs the C++ standard. Cppref is a good reference (the best imho), though if cppref is wrong with regard to this someone should look for the relevant parts in the standard and post an answer. Merely stating that cppref is not the standard is not that relevant for this question

@user12002570 what detail? You just wrote an answer that makes no reference to the actual standard, yet you insist that it is important to point out that only the standard has the correct information. Have a nice day!

@user12002570 cppreferece also doesn't use the term "array declarator" anywhere I can see. It has a page about arrays, in which it shows parts of the grammar applicable to declaring arrays, because it's purpose is to be a reference for C++ programmers, which is different from being a definition for C++ implementors

is this discussion really about the standard mentioning the term "declarator" and declarators that can be used to declare arrays, but not the term "array declarator", or is it about something else? I still honestly wonder whether it is really needed to make this distinction to answer the question.

*array_of_pointers[3] is valid, but it is an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array.
array_of_pointers[3] is matched by noptr-declarator, which is then surrounded by the * to form a ptr-declarator.
Note that when cppreference says that "it has to be surrounded with parentheses", it just refers to what the noptr-declarator rule will match; it's not a statement about language syntax in general.
These separate grammatical rules (noptr-declarator and ptr-declarator) serve two purposes:

Specifying what kind of declarations are valid.
"Layering" the grammar to define precedence rules.

(*pointer_to_abc_array)[3] is also valid. Notice how noptr-declarator can expand to (among other things):

( ptr-declarator )

When parsed by a compiler, (*pointer_to_abc_array)[3] would be matched as a noptr-declarator which includes [3] and a ptr-declarator which is (*pointer_to_abc_array).
Therefore, it would be a pointer to an array, unlike the first example.


Why cppreference says declarator starts with * should be surrounded with parentheses while it also works without them?

Because *array_of_pointers[3] is not an array declarator but a pointer declarator.
This can also be seen from pointer declarator:

A pointer declaration is any simple declaration whose declarator has the form
* attr (optional) cv (optional) declarator    (1)     


Pointer declarator: the declaration S* D; declares D as a pointer to the type determined by decl-specifier-seq S.



Do note that the actual c++ standard does not use the terms "array declarator" but noptr-declartor etc.

The only reason why the standard didn't use "array declarator" is to avoid to repeat "declarator" many times, hence the indentation instead (link taken from @463035818_is_not_an_ai 's comment) but it's obvious that "declarator [newline+indent] array" means "array declarator" or "declarator of an array".

@Fareanor fwiw, neither does the question use the terms.
